# Set Apache echart series dynamically

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have an array of points and want to set the array as the source of series like [text](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack). How can I set series via javascript code dynamically?

My code is:

```
series: this.graph?.data.map(data => {
        return { 
          name: data.label,
          showSymbol: data.showIcon,
          type: 'line',
          lineStyle: {
            width: data.lineTickness ? data.lineTickness : data.isThreshold ? 6 : 1,
            cap: 'round',
            color: data.lineColor ? data.lineColor : null,
            type: data.lineType ? data.lineType.toLowerCase() : null,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            normal: {
                color: data.lineColor ? data.lineColor : null,
            }
          },
          step: data.step,
          data: data.points.map(point => {return point.value?.numeric?.toFixed(4)}),
          areaStyle: data.area ? {} : null,
          yAxisIndex: data.associatedY2Axis ? 1 : 0,
          zlevel: data.isThreshold ? 0 : 1
        }
      })
```

But doesn't work properl and will miss some data on the exported chart.

Comment: zlevel can sometimes cause issues.